# Solve the last equation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, lateral-thinking

My brother showed me the following puzzle from some type of (IQ?) quiz game on his phone:

> 1 + 2 = 21
>   2 + 3 = 36
>   3 + 4 = 43
>   **4 + 5 = ??**

I am quite sure this was the original question asked.

I pondered it for a while and had a few guesses, but none were accepted as "Correct."

I also tried to search on google for it in various ways, but got nowhere.

Comment: It seems easy but it is not. I have a bad feeling that it's some pop-culture reference idk.

Comment: Can you share which guesses were incorrect?

Comment: Are you able to go back to the app and test out further solutions, or are you just wondering if anyone can come up with some logic that works for all terms? (If only that 6 were a 2, eh??)

Comment: Oh.. I guess I know what this game is.. Tbh, I'm also stuck here. Idk if it's a legit logic puzzle or another *trick* silly question. (I dont remember but, have you tried 9?)

Comment: Addressing the concerns in comments: I believe I can still enter in guesses and find out if they are "correct." All of the other questions on this quiz were logical, understandable, seemingly fair. I don't believe that there is any cause for concern in this regard.

Comment: Failed attemts: 58 (20 + **1**, 30 + (1 + 5), 40 + (5 - 2), 50 + (3 + 5) = 58) .... 70 (20 + 1, 30 + 2x3, 40 + **3**, 50 + 4 x 5 = 70). I didn't really like these attempts, they seemed to be unfair, but I'm not sure how fair the answer really is.

Comment: I dismissed the edit to remove the enigmatic-puzzle tag because the method of finding the answer is unclear, aka, an enigma.

Comment: If you look at it from columns then maybe it could be 59?

Comment: [Related xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2032/), with numbers instead of words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Correct Answer was

> 9

Explanation

> The question did not state that the above expressions were correct. The answer was simply 4+5=9

The app is Brain Out, and this is question 58, which answer is shown [in this video](https://youtu.be/OQzqM9RpgV0?t=87).

However, I think this is a very poor answer. Were I the setter of the question, I would treat the + as an unknown operator. A more reasonable answer than the "correct one" would be:

Try

> 52

Explanation:

Tens digit

> is the larger of the two numbers on the LHS, i.e. 5

Units digit

> Goes from 1 --(+2+3)(mod10)-> 6 --(+3+4)(mod10)-> 3 --(+4+5)(mod10)-> 2

Comment: Thanks. I did not expect such a "What kind of cheese is made backwards" kind of question. That being said, I like your "better" answer.

Comment: well, I sure hope it helps ;) @chowzen

Comment: Curious: why did you edit my answer with the source and remove my statement of "I tried to find an answer online" statement instead of simply adding the source to your answer? It's good practice for an OP to state that they have made an effort to find a solution, yet you've removed that??

Comment: Oh, sorry, just thought that wasnt necessary now that you have the source. sorry if you mind, you can edit it back ;)

Answer (score 0):

If "a+b=c" then  if one of them is a prime then c=10b+a , if both are primes then c=a^2*b^2 
Sorry for this..:)

Comment: nice try, but seems that this is not the kind of answer the OP was looking for. beware of downvotes, yet keep up your hard work and happy puzzling :)

Comment: it was just a joke, such thing cannot be the answer.:) (should have posted as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

> 59
>  1+2=21 (2~1) swap places 1+0=1 [21]
>  2+3=36 (3~2) swap places 2+4=6 [36]
>  3+4=43 (4~3) swap places 3+0=3 [43]

---

we can notice a broad pattern altering between adding 0 and 4.

4+5=? applying the same logic we should be getting this answer.
(5~4) swap places 4+4=8. [58]